# Taking input from one PSSession and sending it to another

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, horizon

Like many others, my background is in Linux with no powershell experience. So this object oriented programming is messing me up.

I need to search through VMware Horizon for VMs with users assigned to them, then check if they are disabled in AD. If they are disabled in AD I want to recycle the VM.

At the moment I am pulling the SIDs for the users from VMware Horizon, but when I try to use these in an invoke-command against AD I receive the following error

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

The Script so far

```
function getlist() {
$temp=Invoke-Command -ComputerName $vdiserver -ScriptBlock { add-pssnapin vmware.view.broker; get-desktopvm | select user_sid }
$list=$temp | Select-Object user_sid
#$list
}
$vdi1="server1"
$vdi2="server2"
$test=Test-Connection -ComputerName $vdi1 -Quiet
$test2=Test-Connection -ComputerName $vdi2 -Quiet
if ($test -eq "True"){
$vdiserver=$vdi1
getlist
}
elseif ($test2 -eq "True"){
$vdiserver=$vdi2
getlist
}
else {echo "No servers to connect to"}

ForEach ($user in $list) #{
#echo $user
#sleep 1
#}
{Invoke-Command -ComputerName domaincontroller -ScriptBlock {param($p1) get-aduser -identity $p1 } -argumentlist $user}
```

Comment: Edit and include the error message? Doesn't look like it should happen in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So this object oriented programming is messing me up.

So you're trying to revert to shell script, and writing twice as much code to do achieve half as much work.

The most important bit you're missing is to imagine an object as a collection of things - like, imagine you're working with `/etc/passwd` and each line has a user ID *and* a group ID *and* a home directory *and* a login shell.. and you're passing the entire line around at once, that's your analogous object.

An object has many properties, just like that (but overall more capable).

When you `Select user_sid` you're choosing that field to stay in the 'line', but the line is still something like `:::user_sid::::` with the other fields now empty. (Approximately). But they're still there and in the way. To work with it directly, you have to get it out of the 'line' entirely - throw the container away and just have the user_sid outside of it.

```
get-desktopvm | select user_sid

->

get-desktopvm | select -expandproperty user_sid
```

which makes `"sid1", "sid2", "sid3"`, but no containers for each sid.

---

This

```
function getlist() {
    $temp=Invoke-Command -ComputerName $vdiserver -ScriptBlock { add-pssnapin vmware.view.broker; get-desktopvm | select user_sid }
    $list=$temp | Select-Object user_sid
}
```

is essentially saying

```
function getlist() {
    #do any amount of work here, and throw it all away.
}
```

Because the function returns nothing, and it doesn't change any data on disk or anything, so when the function finishes, the variables are cleared out of memory, and you can't use them afterwards.

---

This:

```
if ($test -eq "True"){
```

is a bit of a nonsense. It might work, but it's not working how you expect because it's happenstance that "a string with content" compared to a boolean True is True, regardless of the string containing the English word "True" or not. But it's also redundant - `$test` is itself true or false, you don't need to compare True with anything.  `if ($test)`. Or even `if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $vdi -Quiet)`

---

But stillll, so much work. Just connect to them all, and let it fail for the ones it can't contact. Maybe add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` if you don't want to see the error.

```
$VMs = Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server1,Server2 -ScriptBlock { 
    Add-PsSnapin vmware.view.broker
    Get-DesktopVm 
}
```

Now you have all the VMs, get the user enabled/disabled state

```
foreach ($VM in $VMs) {

    $Sid = $VM.user_sid

    $AdEnabled = Invoke-Command -ComputerName domaincontroller -ScriptBlock {
        (Get-AdUser -Identity $using:Sid).Enabled
    }

    $VM| Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'AdEnabled' -NotePropertyValue $AdEnabled

}
```

Now you should ideally have $VM as an array of objects, each one having all the VM Desktop properties - and also the True/False state of the AD Enabled property for that user account.

```
$VM | Out-Gridview
```

or

```
$VM | Export-Csv Report.csv
```

or

```
$VM | Where-Object { -not $_.AdEnabled }
```

Comment: Nail on the head, I keep wanting to work with stdout and apply my own perceptual relative logic to everything. Thank you for going out of your way to explain each step. The only comment I have so far is that I am able to call the variable, created from the function, later in the script (you can see the commented lines where I test this).

Comment: My next question is related to the testing of server availability. Let's say the first server responds while the second errors out. Wouldn't the failed connection overwrite the variable created from the working server with the error? Or does powershell recognize an error took place and makes no changes when this happens?

Comment: I don't understant how your commented out test lines work. If you make a simple test file `function getlist { $list = get-childitem c:\ }; getlist; $list` and run it in a fresh powershell session, there's no output. (I just tried it now). Regarding the server availability - in my version all the output of `Invoke-Command` is kept, there's no overwriting. Any server that responds, its output goes into `$VMs`. If one server responds you get its output, if both respond you get both their get-desktopvm results together in `$VMs`. If neither responds you get nothing.

Comment: What's funny is that I had that issue when I started, where the variable from the function would get removed, and I did something in order to get it to stick but I don't remember what. Will have to go back and do some testing. Again, thank you for your time.

Comment: Found out why it was "working", I was working inside of ISE which does not clear variables between runs. So at one point I had created the variable while not using the function and it stuck for consecutive runs.